# Binary representation - conversion in C++

Tags: binary, numbers

```
a = 13;
for (b = 8∗ sizeof(int)−1; b >= 0; b−−)
    cout << ( (a & (1U << b)) > 0 );
```

May anybody explain me, what happen in "cout"? Is it a condition?
I mean, why it must be "> 0" ? 
And what's the correct order of action in this "cout"?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`(a & (1U << b)) > 0` returns 1 if the check passes and 0 if it does not. This result is what is printed by `cout`. `&` performs a bitwise and operation on two integers and `1U << b` performs a left bitshift of `1` by `b` bits (the `U` just tells the compiler to treat the value as unsigned).